# Propel2 diff detects non-existent changes with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, propel, propel2

I'm using Propel2 ORM w/ PostgreSQL, this is my configuration:

```
propel:
database:
    connections:
        default:
            adapter: pgsql
            dsn: pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=sps_db
            user: postgres
            password: postgres
            settings:
                charset: utf8
```

This is my sample schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xsd.propelorm.org/1.6/database.xsd" >
<table name="product" description="Available products table">
    <column name="id_product" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true" type="BIGINT" required="true"/>
    <column name="id_product_barcode" type="BIGINT" />
    <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="200" required="true" />
    <column name="id_product_manufacturer" type="INTEGER" required="true" />
    <column name="id_product_category" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="id_product_photo" type="BIGINT" />
</table>
</database>
```

PostgreSQL 9.5 has been fresh installed on Ubuntu 16.04.
When I run `propel diff` and `propel migrate` the first time everything is OK and the tables are generated.

Here is the first generated migration: http://pastebin.com/hK9qwfeA

If, without changing the schema, I re-run diff propel detects changes (which are non-existent):

```
Comparing models...
Structure of database was modified in datasource "default": 1 modified tables
```

With the following generated migration file: http://pastebin.com/Yx143CKp

Of course, if I execute the migration file SQL complains:

```
  [PDOException]                                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42701]: Duplicate column: 7 ERROR:  column "id_product" of relation "product" already exists
```

I can't really figure out what's happening. All of the above, with a much more complex schema (and with this one, too) works correctly w/ MySQL.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: this is the SQL from pgSql for the table generated in the first migration:

```
CREATE TABLE public.product
(
  id_product bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('product_id_product_seq'::regclass),
  id_product_barcode bigint,
  name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  id_product_manufacturer integer NOT NULL,
  id_product_category integer NOT NULL,
  id_product_photo bigint,
  CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_product)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.product
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON TABLE public.product
  IS 'Available products table';
```

Comment: For the records, I switched to Doctrine 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Downgrading PostgreSQL 9.5.x to 9.4.8 solved this problem for me.

It may be a bug in 9.5.x.

Comment: Please leave this answer alone. If correct, it provides crucial information. If anything, edit to improve it.

Comment: I guess this is the right answer as it solves the problem, although indirectly

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging and investigation (we figured it was a 9.5 metadata change) we found the following:

https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/pull/1245

It comes down to a simple trim command when splitting the schema in postgresql 9.5